# Retrieving security descriptor and getting number for FileSystemRights

Tags: powershell, acl

Using `Get-Acl` I am trying to get the access rights on a folder. The thing is, for some groups I get a number instead of a access type. Example below:

```
get-acl "C:\TestFolder" | % {$_.access}
FileSystemRights  : -536805376
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : TestDomain\Support
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : InheritOnly
```

Is there any way to translate this number back to its name?

Answer (score 15):

The value of the `FileSystemRights` property is an unsigned 32-bit integer, where each bit represents a particular access permission. Most of the permissions are listed in the [`Win32_ACE` class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394063.aspx), except for the "generic" permissions (bits 28-31) and the right to access SACLs (bit 23). More details can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc982153.aspx).

If you want to break down an ACE access mask into its specific access rights (vulgo "extended permissions") you could do something like this:

```psh
$accessMask = [ordered]@{
  [uint32]'0x80000000' = 'GenericRead'
  [uint32]'0x40000000' = 'GenericWrite'
  [uint32]'0x20000000' = 'GenericExecute'
  [uint32]'0x10000000' = 'GenericAll'
  [uint32]'0x02000000' = 'MaximumAllowed'
  [uint32]'0x01000000' = 'AccessSystemSecurity'
  [uint32]'0x00100000' = 'Synchronize'
  [uint32]'0x00080000' = 'WriteOwner'
  [uint32]'0x00040000' = 'WriteDAC'
  [uint32]'0x00020000' = 'ReadControl'
  [uint32]'0x00010000' = 'Delete'
  [uint32]'0x00000100' = 'WriteAttributes'
  [uint32]'0x00000080' = 'ReadAttributes'
  [uint32]'0x00000040' = 'DeleteChild'
  [uint32]'0x00000020' = 'Execute/Traverse'
  [uint32]'0x00000010' = 'WriteExtendedAttributes'
  [uint32]'0x00000008' = 'ReadExtendedAttributes'
  [uint32]'0x00000004' = 'AppendData/AddSubdirectory'
  [uint32]'0x00000002' = 'WriteData/AddFile'
  [uint32]'0x00000001' = 'ReadData/ListDirectory'
}

$fileSystemRights = Get-Acl -LiteralPath 'C:\some\folder_or_file' |
                    Select-Object -Expand Access |
                    Select-Object -Expand FileSystemRights -First 1

$permissions = $accessMask.Keys |
               Where-Object { $fileSystemRights.value__ -band $_ } |
               ForEach-Object { $accessMask[$_] }
```

The simple permissions `FullControl`, `Modify`, `ReadAndExecute` etc. are just specific combinations of these extended permissions. `ReadAndExecute` for instance is a combination of the following extended permissions:

- `ReadData/ListDirectory`
- `Execute/Traverse`
- `ReadAttributes`
- `ReadExtendedAttributes`
- `ReadControl`

so the access mask for `ReadAndExecute` would have the value 131241.

If you want the result to be a combination of simple permission and the remaining extended permissions, you could do something like this:

```psh
$accessMask = [ordered]@{
  ...
}

$simplePermissions = [ordered]@{
  [uint32]'0x1f01ff' = 'FullControl'
  [uint32]'0x0301bf' = 'Modify'
  [uint32]'0x0200a9' = 'ReadAndExecute'
  [uint32]'0x02019f' = 'ReadAndWrite'
  [uint32]'0x020089' = 'Read'
  [uint32]'0x000116' = 'Write'
}

$fileSystemRights = Get-Acl -LiteralPath 'C:\some\folder_or_file' |
                    Select-Object -Expand Access |
                    Select-Object -Expand FileSystemRights -First 1

$fsr = $fileSystemRights.value__

$permissions = @()

# get simple permission
$permissions += $simplePermissions.Keys | ForEach-Object {
                  if (($fsr -band $_) -eq $_) {
                    $simplePermissions[$_]
                    $fsr = $fsr -band (-bnot $_)
                  }
                }

# get remaining extended permissions
$permissions += $accessMask.Keys |
                Where-Object { $fsr -band $_ } |
                ForEach-Object { $accessMask[$_] }
```

Comment: Great answer although there is a typo in `$fsr = $fsr -band (-bNOT $_)`. Note binary `-bNOT` instead of logical `-not` .

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Quick and dirty tanslation:

268435456 - FullControl

-536805376 - Modify, Synchronize

-1610612736 - ReadAndExecute, Synchronize

If you want to learn about the translation process this was the best i could find at the moment: 
[Link](http://blog.cjwdev.co.uk/2011/06/28/permissions-not-included-in-net-accessrule-filesystemrights-enum/)